# ajax render template versus partial stack level error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Been away from rails for about a year and trying to remember everything by experimenting with a prototype. I inherited the scaffold template to provide a Show view that allows drilling down to related has_many models.There are some deeply nested models but I never go more that 1 deep and use the show view to drill down.

```
fieldset
    show fields from models
    actions on model
related action menubar (links to load related records with js)
fieldset
    related index view
```

By default, the primary related models index view is rendered as a template from the show view, often from the index.html.erb of the related model. Using routing, most of the related index views can also be rendered on its own page. I did about 8 models using this scheme, but the last one I tried gave me a `ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep):` error trying to load the .js template hundreds of times and never loading the template called for in the .js file.

```
Started GET "/events/2/participants" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-21 05:39:56 -0600
Processing by EventsController#participants as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Event Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
  Rendered events/participants.js.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered events/participants.js.erb (1.9ms)
  ...  
  Rendered events/participants.js.erb (486.2ms)
  Rendered events/participants.js.erb (487.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 496ms

ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep):
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23
```

A working controller actions and the .js line:

```
def stages
  @commitment = Commitment.find(params[:id])
  @stages = @commitment.stages.page(params[:page]).per(10)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
    format.html {render :template => "stages/index"}
  end
end

<stages.js.erb>
$("#related").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:template => 'stages/index'))%>");
```

Notice the .js file renders the template from the stages view.

The same stuff for the controller that gave me a problem:

```
def participants
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @participants = @event.participants
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
    format.html {render :template => "events/participants"}
  end
end

<participants.js.erb>
$("#related").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:template => 'events/participants'))%>");
```

The only difference is that the index is in the Events view (no Participants views/controllers). The default template will load without the render hash on format.html, but left it to be consistent.

After scratching my head for a few hours trying to find any other differences. I made participants.html.erb a partial and changed the .js line to

$("#related").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'events/participants'))%>");

That worked, no errors, both js and html work(participants.html.erb renders partial)!

Since I got it working I guess I don't have a question other than why the different behavior for a template versus a partial? Or, is there something else I need to learn?

Steve